# Button Click On JSP

Tags: asp.net, jsp

I am ASP.NET Developer, New To JSP. How can i perform Button Click event in JSP ?

I Want to Execute the Code in Server Side not in Javascript. I Know That I can achieve it By Servelets. I Have Some Questions Regarding This.

1.) I Have 30 Pages in My JSP Project. Do I Have to Create 30 Servelets ?

2.) Is There Any Page Load Event In JSP Similar to ASP.NET ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Have 30 Pages in My JSP Project. Do I Have to Create 30 Servelets ?

Not necessarily. May be a single servlet perform one or more task(s).

> Is There Any Page Load Event In JSP Similar to ASP.NET ?

Yes, it is `void jspInit() { ... }` but use of Java code in JSPs is is highly *discouraged*.

---

You can determine which `submit` button is pressed in Servlet's doPost/Get method by reading request parameter.

**TestServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "test", urlPatterns = {"/test"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String button=request.getParameter("cmd");
        if(button.equals("Add")){
           //
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**test.jsp**

```
                            |----- servlet url /test 
                            V
<form method="post" action="test">
  <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Add"/>
  <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

So Is it Advisable to Use 1 Servlet for all 30 Pages ?

Comment: *Some* webapp *frameworks* uses *single* controller [Servlet](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=2461)